# My application runs on WinXP but fails to start on Win7

Tags: windows-7, mingw32

I compiled my application on Linux via MinGW (32-bit). My application runs as expected on Windows XP (SP2 & SP3, 32-bit OS), but it fails on Windows 7 (SP1, 64-bit OS). It throws this message:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application
```

How to solve this?

Comment: One of the DLLs you use returned FALSE from its DllMain() entrypoint.  That's all that can be guessed at from the error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Dependency Walker to trace which DLL is missing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/06/25/analyze-application-failures-the-easier-way-with-dependency-walker.aspx). Load the Exe in depends and press <kbd>F7</kbd> to start the profiler.

[image]

Click here `ok` to start profiling:

[image]

After you get the error message you should see missing DLLs shown in Depends.exe.

[image]

Comment: It is not a missing DLL problem.

Comment: I found that glew32.dll which was built on linux before via mingw32 has initialization problems on Windows 7... This DllMain() of this library returns 0 (0x0).